# How to replace a dictionary values to keys of a dictionary and its keys to values

Tags: python, dictionary, get, dictionary-comprehension

Does someone here know what I am doing wrong?
I need to get a new dictionary from the keys, based in its values...
For instance, if I have the following dictionary

```
dic = {'b':1, 'i':2, 'c':2, 'l':1, 'e':1, 'a':1}
```

I need to get a new dictionary which looks like this

```
newdic = {1:['b', 'l', 'e', 'a'],2:['i', 'c']
```

Or perhaps something else with a dictionary comprehension
I have the following code which is not working properly

```
newdic={}

dic = {'b':1, 'i':2, 'c':2, 'l':1, 'e':1, 'a':1}
for letter in dic:
  newdic[dic.get(letter)] = [newdic.get(dic.get(letter), [])].append(letter)

print(newdic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it using a dictionary comprehension but it is less readable:

```
>>> {v: [k for k, v1 in dic.items() if v == v1] for v in dic.values()}
{1: ['b', 'l', 'e', 'a'], 2: ['i', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `collections.defaultdict` and a simple loop to reverse your data.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reverse_dict(inp):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in inp.items():
        output[v].append(k)
    return dict(output)

output = reverse_dict(dic)
print(output)
#{1: ['b', 'l', 'e', 'a'], 2: ['i', 'c']}
```

Comment: Isn't possible to resolve this though a dict comprehension, @PacketLoss?

Comment: Of course if is, however you have to add an additional loop (as in the accepted answer). This may be slower over larger data sets and is also less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
newdic={}
dic = {'b':1, 'i':2, 'c':2, 'l':1, 'e':1, 'a':1}

for letter in dic:
    if dic[letter] not in newdic:
        newdic[dic[letter]] = []
    newdic[dic[letter]].append(letter)

print(newdic)
```

The problem with the get method is that you do not create the key. The equality only adds the keys, but does not append the letter.